# NHibernate/Oracle : how to insert large number in BINARY_DOUBLE column?

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate-mapping, ora-01426

I have a C# System.Double property which may contains value like 1e250 :

```
public virtual double DoubleValue {get; set;}
```

The property is mapped to a BINARY_DOUBLE column :

```
<property name="DoubleValue" column="VALUE_BINARY_DOUBLE"/>
```

Max value for Binary_Double is about 1.7e+308 ([Oracle doc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#i140176)), but I'm getting an exception :
ORA-01426 : numeric overflow

Problem appears even when executing a query through SQL+. I have to use the TO_BINARY_DOUBLE cast to make it work. In my understanding, the number supplied is implicitly converted to a NUMBER : my query work with 1e125 (max for NUMBER is 1e126) but won't work with 1e250.

I've also tried those mappings, without success :

```
<property name="DoubleValue" column="VALUE_BINARY_DOUBLE" type="System.Double"/>
<property name="DoubleValue" column="VALUE_BINARY_DOUBLE" type="binary"/>
```

Using : Oracle 11G - NHibernate 2.1.0 - .Net 3.5 SP1

Thanks for any lead you may provide !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the workaround we are using, since we didn't find any solution :
Add a property in C# :

```
public virtual string DatabaseDoubleValue
{
    get
    {
        return DoubleValue.ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        DoubleValue = double.Parse(value);
    }
}
```

Change mapping to

```
<property name="DatabaseDoubleValue" column="VALUE_BINARY_DOUBLE"/>
```

Add a trigger on the VALUE_BINARY_DOUBLE column :

```
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.VALUE_BINARY_DOUBLE := TO_BINARY_DOUBLE(:NEW.VALUE_BINARY_DOUBLE);
END;
```

Works fine that way!